# Find the minimum number of switches to be turned on for illuminating the binary tree

Tags: algorithm

Consider a binary tree like:

[image]

Think of the nodes as switches, which are initially `OFF` and the edges between nodes as tube lights (not glowing initially). When we switch on a particular node, then all the edges(tube lights) connected to that node glow. Find the minimum number of switches that need to be turned `ON` for the whole binary tree to glow.

For example, if I switch on `2,3,4 and 9` or `2,3,8,9` then all the tube lights glow. So, the answer is `4` [see the diagram]

I was asked about this question in an interview. Can anyone help me with the algorithm/pseudocode? No need for working code.

For programmers and coders, think that the input is like:

`n`: the number of edges given

Then `n` lines follow in the form `x y` where `x` and `y` are two endpoints of the edge.

According to the diagram above, the input will be:

```
10
1 2
1 3
2 5
...
```

Till now, I have figured out a few cases like: **I never need to illuminate the leaf nodes**

Is a simple recursive solution present based on the above fact?

**Edit:** Will the algorithm change if only the `Root` of the tree is given as `input` [Assume the tree is represented as a linked list] ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it recursively by considering what is the minimum number of switches that need to be turned on for each sub-tree, assuming the root node is on and also assuming it is off.

If the root node is on then the child nodes can be either on or off, so `minSwitchesAssumingRootOn` calls `minSwitches` recursively. If the root node is off then the child nodes must be on for the edges connected to the root node to be on, so `minSwitchesAssumingRootOff` calls `minSwitchesAssumingRootOn` recursively.

The sub-totals can be stored using memo-ization to speed it up. `tree.minAssumingOff` and `tree.minAssumingOn` should be initialized to -1.

Pseudo-code:

```
int minSwitches(tree)
{
    if(tree == null)
        return 0;
    return min(minSwitchesAssumingRootOff(tree),
       minSwitchesAssumingRootOn(tree));
}

int minSwitchesAssumingRootOn(tree)
{
    if(tree == null)
        return 0;
    if(tree.minAssumingOn == -1)
        tree.minAssumingOn = 1 + minSwitches(tree.left) + minSwitches(tree.right);
    return tree.minAssumingOn;
}

int minSwitchesAssumingRootOff(tree)
{
    if(tree == null)
        return 0;
    if(tree.minAssumingOff == -1)
        tree.minAssumingOff = minSwitchesAssumingRootOn(tree.left) + 
            minSwitchesAssumingRootOn(tree.right);
    return tree.minAssumingOff;
}
```

Comment: @User_Targaryen with memo-ization added I think it's O(n)

Answer (score 4):

This is a minimum vertex cover problem (MVC) on trees. You can solve it in two way:

1. Tree is a bipartite graph and MVC problem is equivalent to finding a maximum matching which is polynomial time solvable.
2. Do it by a greedy algorithm as follows. Root the tree arbitrarily. Select all vertices connected to the leaves and put them in the final set (turn on them). (either those vertices or leaves should be in final solution). Remove those vertices and all the edges and leave vertices connected to them and proceed by the same algorithm on the rest of the graph.

Here is the proof why the algorithm works:
Suppose input is a forest of size 'n'. Clearly either a leaf or its neighbor should be turned on (except that it has no edge connected to it). So the first step is correct.

Once we remove all parents of leaves and all leaves the remaining graph is a forest on 'n-t' vertices where t is the number of leaves and their parent in the original graph. Suppose we know what are the leave nodes at start. We do the following to solve the problem in `O(n)`:

If we know what are the leaves after deletion of those 't' vertices then we solve the problem in `T(n) = O(t) + T(n-t)` where results in `T(n) = O(n)`. To find new leaves after deletion of those `t` vertices, we create a new leaves list. each time we delete either of those `t` vertices we check if they have a neighbour of degree one which was not connected to the original leaves and we add that vertex to the new leave list. After we finish the process of removing leaves and their neighbours we update the original leaves list with the new leaves list. So in each step we have leaves list and therefore it can be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: Can you mention the complexity of each of your solution?

Comment: @User_Targaryen, First one is not very good but there are lots of code for it, the second one is O(n).

Comment: @Saeed The 2nd solution you posted is exactly what I was thinking. Turn on all the nodes 1 level above the leaves and delete all of them from the graph and recurse. But I'm wondering what the complexity would be.

Comment: @AneeshDandime, If you implement it correctly it is O(n), btw, I've just edited the second solution a bit, there was a mistake in it. I'll write the proof and complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: You need to remove all the leaves, nodes you turned on and the edges that started glowing because of the node you turned on and then recurse right?

Comment: @AneeshDandime, I updated to explain how it works and why it works and why it is O(n).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I've just implemented your second idea. Used BFS and inserts leaves first thus keeping track of new leaves while poping. Its `O(V + E)` ~ `0(n)` as its tree.

Comment: @KaidulIslam, Good job, Yes, It's O(|V|+|E|) but on trees it's O(|V|).

Comment: BTW, It doesn't work on non-trees (because we need leaves)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I did keeping mind it will only work for tree.

Comment: You can use a single bottom-up (i.e., postorder) DFS to accomplish the same thing as your O(n) solution.  (This isn't better asymptotically, but it will reduce the constant factor quite a bit by avoiding deletions and other bookkeeping.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, Yes simple DFS can work as well, but we should keep track of leaves otherwise it runs in O(n^2). I thought explanation in this way is better for understanding.

Comment: I agree that your explanation is clearer :)  If nodes are numbered 1, 2, 3, ... with 0 indicating an absent child, then set `leftChild[0] = rightChild[0] = 1` and the DFS can then be as simple as `visit(int v) { if (v) { visit(leftChild[v]); visit(rightChild[v]); isOn[v] = !isOn[leftChild[v]] || !isOn[rightChild[v]]; } }`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, Your algorithm is by assuming that the input tree is really a binary tree and furthermore assuming that we have the correct ordering for that. But the algorithm in my answer is more general: if the input graph is a forest.

Comment: OK, but... the OP's question is for a binary tree!  (Also what do you mean by "the correct ordering"?  My `visit()` can easily be adapted to any adjacency list representation without overhead; just pass an extra vertex ID, `parent`, as an argument, and replace `leftChild[v]` with an expression that chooses the smallest non-`parent` neighbour vertex ID, and `rightChild[v]` with an expression that chooses the largest non-`parent` neighbour vertex ID.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, what you said for extension is wrong, I'll ask you to find the mistake yourself (it's possible to modify it though). But yes the Q is for binary trees and I just wrote a general O(n) approach.

Comment: I can't tell whether you mean that something is wrong with my original `visit()`, or with the modification to handle the usual adjacency list representation for general graphs, but I don't see any problem with either.  If you want to convince me that there's really a problem, you'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The question is similar to this one on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-cameras/
My solution

```
// -1 -> need cam 
//  0  -> has cam
//  1  -> covered by child

int cam;
class Solution {
public:
    int solve(TreeNode* root){
        if(root==NULL){
            return 1;
        }
        int l = solve(root->left);
        int r = solve(root->right);
        if(l==-1 || r==-1){    //if any child node node need a cam this node must have a cam
            cam++;
            return 0;
        }
        if(l==0 || r==0){    //if any child node has cam this node doesn't need a cam its covered by child
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;     //else its need a cam
        
    }
    int minCameraCover(TreeNode* root){
        cam=0;
        if(solve(root)==-1){  //if root need a cam
            cam++;
        }
        return cam;
    }
};
```